# Does annotating a repository interface as @Component have any cons?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, interface, spring-annotations

I have this interface:

```
public interface liteRepository extends CrudRepository<liteEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<liteEntity> {...}
```

It works, all is well.

However, `intellij` does not register this class as a spring component. If I annotate this interface with `@Component`, then `intellij` recognizes this as a spring bean and I can `@Autowire` this repository in my integration tests.

My code still works after annotation, but I'm not confident that I am not messing with things that I should not be messing with.

**Question:**
Is there any harm in adding the `@Component` annotation to this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that `@Component` annotation means is that the class is eligible for becoming a Spring bean during Spring's component-scan.

So, if you want it to be a Spring bean and you did not define it as a Spring bean anywhere else, you can safely add the `@Component` annotation.

Of course, this will only work if you have the actual component scan configured somewhere(for, example `<context:component-scan base-package="...">` in some Spring config file), which I am assuming you already heave, since the bean is properly getting autowired after you add the annotation.